# Ionic on iOS not sending request to external Api

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I have custom api written in WebApi2 that serves some data in json. I'm trying to access that particular API from Ionic on iOS and Android using Angular's $http. On Android everything is ok and I'm receiving correct result. But on iOS strange thing happens, as $http even don't send request and throws error immidiately, returning http status code 0. This problem exists only on iOS emulator and iPhone. Moreover, this behavior is not observable when requesting any other site or fake test api.

What I already tried:

- Add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" header.
- Add proxy to ionic.project, but this fixed the problem only when running Ionic Serve
- Add  in config.xml
- configure angular to use cross-domain by setting this:

  $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
  delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

Any clues? Maybe this is server-side problem?

Answer (score 0):

Does this also happen on an iOS version lower than 9.0? Because there has been some problems with $http since iOS 9.0. If it doesn't, it would check out [this](https://www.ekreative.com/blog/adapting-my-ionic-framework-hybrid-mobile-app-for-ios-9-problems-and-solutions) article.

> Looking for solutions
>
> When I started searching for this error I found this forum thread. It
>   said that the contributors had got this error too and that the error
>   is triggered when a network request is made using the $http service. I
>   used $http in my app too, but I didn’t make any request through it
>   when the app was starting. Also, in the forum thread it said that the
>   problem is triggered by adding custom headers to a network request. To
>   solve the problem, headers shouldn’t have a leading space in the
>   value. I had custom headers but I didn't have any spaces before the
>   value. So I decided, (wrongly as it turned out), that this article
>   couldn't help me.
>
> Here’s what I tried next:
>
> I read all the advice from Ionic's blog article again and tried to
>   apply it to my project - it didn’t help. I decided that as I was
>   getting the error in vendor files, I should try updating Ionic
>   Framework, Ionic CLI and all third party libraries (Angular,
>   Restangular, ngStorage, ...) - it took some time, but when I ran the
>   app again I got the same error. I created a new "clear" ionic app and
>   it worked properly - so I was sure that the problem was somewhere in
>   my code. I started debugging the app and digging around in my code in
>   "the old school way" - trying to cut out blocks of code and see if the
>   app would then work (because I got the error before it was possible to
>   use any Safari dev tools for debugging). In this way I found out which
>   line in my code was triggering this error. It was this line:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ' + $localStorage.user.authToken;
```

> I use my own service in dependency
>   injection which executes a line of code (see above) when the service
>   is initialized. This is why the $http service was also causing the
>   error I was encountering. I removed this line from my code and
>   replaced it with authorization token headers in the configuration of
>   each request, like this:

```
 $http.post(appConfig.apiUrl + 'profile', data, {  headers: {'Authorization': $localStorage.user.authToken} })
```

> After that my app started to load (Hurrah) which let me see some other
>   problems (Booo).

Comment: Request to other sites works fine. So that can't be problem with custom headers, as I'm not adding any.